# Problema con NODE js y npx creando proyecto

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, vscode, next

Tengo dificultad con la creacion de un proyecto con node.js, npx el problema es que me da un error

```js
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\proyecto-react\01\.next\BUILD_ID'] {  
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\proyecto-react\\01\\.next\\BUILD_ID'
```

y no he podido saber como solucionarlo incluyo las imaganes para que si puede alguin ayudarme muchas gracias [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Abre `package.json` y verifica cuales son los comandos, probablemente tienes algo así:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start",
  "lint": "next lint"
},
```

Lo cual para usar `npm start` tendrías que generar primero el build con `npm build`, como se indica en la documentación de Next.j CLI:

> Production
> next start starts the application in production mode. The application should be compiled with next build first.
> The application will start at http://localhost:3000 by default. The default port can be changed with -p, like so:

[API Reference: Next.js CLI | Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-cli)